# Do not clear form while moving through it

Tags: html

I am using a form for a JS app.
But every time I move from one input field to another (not submit) the entire form clears.
Here is my form (ignore non English words)

```
        <form class="formular formular-pitanja" id="formular-pitanja">
          <div>
            <label for="tekst-pitanja">Tekst pitanja</label>
            <textarea name="tekst-pitanja" id="tekst-pitanja" class="tekst-pitanja" placeholder="Unesi tekst pitanja"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="kategorijaZaPitanja">Izaberi kategoriju</label>
            <select name="kategorijaZaPitanja" id="kategorijaZaPitanja">
              <option value="B">B</option>
              <option value="C">C</option>
              <option value="Prva-pomoć">Prva pomoć</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="odgovor">Unesi odgovor</label>
            <input type="text" id="odgovor" name="odgovor" placeholder="Unesi odgovor">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="vrijednost-pitanja">Vrijednost pitanja</label>
            <input type="number" class="vrijednost-pitanja" id="vrijednost-pitanja" name="vrijednost-pitanja" placeholder="Unesi vrijednost">
          </div>

          <div class="tasteri tasteri-pitanja">
            <input type="button" id="dodajOdgovor" class="dodaj-odgovor" value="Dodaj odgovor">
            <button id="dodaj-pitanje" class="dodaj-pitanje">Sačuvaj pitanje</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Is this a default behaviour, or did I do something to cause this? Can I remove this behaviour?

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript code running? Are you tabbing through the input fields or navigating with your mouse?

Comment: I imagine the important part here is the "JS app" which isn't included in the question. Changing which input is focused won't clear anything in a basic HTML form (As you can see by testing just the code you have included on its own)

Comment: I just tried it on https://jsfiddle.net/ and it's not clearing the values as I click or tab through the form, so there must be some JS or other aspect that's causing this problem. It's definitely not default behavior.

Comment: Thanks, folks. So it turns out the form was inside a modal, which in turn had a modal background. I had a click listener on that background to close the modal. But inside the handler function, I put the function which clears the form (god only knows when and why). So when I clicked anywhere inside the form the click event bubbled to the modal background and triggered the function which cleared the form. Thanks again to all of you.